# How to draw QtGraphicsView on Top of QVideoWidget with transparency

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qtmultimedia

I am trying to overlay some graphics(QtGraphicsView) on top of video player(QVideoWidget). i have already tried setting QtGraphicsView subclass stylesheets to transparent and background brush and none is working.

```
#self.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(30, 30, 30, 3)))
#self.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)")
#self.setStyleSheet("background:rgba(0,0,0,0)")
self.setStyleSheet("background:transparent")
self.setStyleSheet("background-color:transparent")
self.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgba(30,30,30,3)")
self.setStyleSheet("background:rgba(30,30,30,3)")
```

Actual Intentions is to easily crop a video (visual way). All other work is done regarding capturing events , doing math etc.  this image explains situation pretty well.[image: pyqt5 ui] . At this point it feels, surely i am doing it wrong way, there must be some easier way in QtMultiMedia Components to draw on top of them. Any Ideas really appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One possible solution is to use QGraphicsVideoItem instead of QVideoWidget and embed it in the QGraphicsView, then the other items can be made child of the QGraphicsVideoItem so that it is on top, besides the position of the new items will be related to the QGraphicsVideoItem.

```
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia, QtMultimediaWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self._scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self._gv = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self._scene)

        self._videoitem = QtMultimediaWidgets.QGraphicsVideoItem()
        self._scene.addItem(self._videoitem)
        self._ellipse_item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsEllipseItem(QtCore.QRectF(50, 50, 40, 40), self._videoitem)
        self._ellipse_item.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.green))
        self._ellipse_item.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red))

        self._player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer(self, QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self._player.stateChanged.connect(self.on_stateChanged)
        self._player.setVideoOutput(self._videoitem)

        file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "small.mp4")
        self._player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(file)))
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Play")
        button.clicked.connect(self._player.play)

        self.resize(640, 480)
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self._gv)
        lay.addWidget(button)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.State)
    def on_stateChanged(self, state):
        if state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self._gv.fitInView(self._videoitem, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]